# Google Cloud Functions Node 8 not working – "hidden" dependencies expecting Node 6?

Tags: firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

I've been using Google Cloud Functions with the regular Node 6 runtime for about 18 months, and it's all mostly fine and dandy. However, I've unsuccessfully tried to get it working with Node 8.

Package.json (server/functions folder) below:

```
{
"engines": {
    "node": "8"
},
"name": "project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.17.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"
},
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
}
```

Specifically, the error I get is on running a function, where it will error out on "semver" expecting a different Node version (6?).

Is there something I can do, or some workaround, for this to work at all? I can't even install firebase-tools v4+ here, although I can do so in my root directory where it's already installed.

Comment: I'm not tracking what the problem is here.  What do you mean by "error out on 'semver'?  Do you have a specific error message?  Is the CLI generating that on deploy?  Please edit the question to walk me through what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Doug! Sorry for the unclarity. Following [this](https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-joyride/issues/131) made me understand that the local install issue could be fixed by using NPM rather than Yarn. Somehow it seems that issue would follow along to the actual cloud function as well? Removing yarn.lock and reinstalling the local modules with NPM fixed the issue, even on the deployed function that would previously break with an error pointing to an unrelated/hidden (?) module (Semver, in our case) not being found.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that's related to Cloud Functions.

Comment: Precisely, but I just learned that now. The error manifested itself firstly through running Cloud Functions which would break, thus why I thought that those could be the problem. They were not: For anyone having a similar issue, it's worth wiping the modules and using NPM exclusively since that seems to fix the problem. Yarn does not work for managing Node.8 modules in a GCF project, it seems.

I will close this.